# Как сделать изменения в классе из библиотеки если доступ закрыт?

Tags: java, android

Есть Библиотека и нужно в  него добавить некоторые методы ...Как мне это Реализовать?Дохожу до класса а на нем  стоит знак замочка ,просмотреть могу а изменить нет ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Существует несколько способов.

Самый простой - поискать исходники данной библиотеки на гитхабе или связаться с разработчиком. Изменить что нужно в исходном коде и собрать библиотеку, опционально - сделать pull request.

Следующий по сложности вариант - отнаследоваться от нужного класса и переопределить нужный метод. Проблемы в том, что нужно будет создавать объект именно вашего класса (если он создаётся внутри библиотеки - плохо). Так же проблемы со статическими или финальными методами.

Самый сложный - полностью декомпилировать библиотеку и заменить нужный метод. Для декомпиляции существует множество программ (jd-gui, procyclon и так далее). Все они имеют свои особенности, метод требует аккуратности ну и с правовой стороной будьте аккуратны.

Comment: тот мод который я хочу он уже есть на Гит-е и с pull request .Я могу его запустить у себя ?у него там весь исходный код измененный есть

Comment: @elik конечно. Проще всего удалить саму библиотеку из проекта и просто добавить в проект весь код скачанный с гитхаба.